# Replace spaces with dashes, but only for text found between quotes in the text TAGS=""

Tags: regex, notepad++

Is it possible to do the following with Notepad++'s FIND/REPLACE function?

I have a text file where I want to replace spaces found in between the quotes of the text `TAGS="*"` with dashes.

Example:

```
TAGS="tag1,tag2,tag 3,tag4,tag 5"
```

should become:

```
TAGS="tag1,tag2,tag-3,tag4,tag-5"
```

So far I can find the text I want using:

```
FIND WHAT: TAGS="*"
```

But how do I have it replace spaces with dashes?

--------------------- UPDATE -----------------
My question before used tag1,tag2, but the actual data in the file does not have numbers, only words.

These following are three actual lines from the file. I need to find spaces between the quotes of TAGS="*" and replace only those spaces with dashes:

```
<DT><A HREF="http://www.kundaliniyoga.org/pranayam.html" ADD_DATE="1452557806" LAST_VISIT="1452557806" LAST_MODIFIED="1452557806" TAGS="kundalini,yoga,fire breath,breathing,breath of fire">Kundalini Yoga - Pranayama - Breathing Techniques</A>
<DT><A HREF="http://www.foodrepublic.com/2015/05/19/40-ways-world-makes-awesome-hot-dogs" ADD_DATE="1432954394" LAST_VISIT="1432954394" LAST_MODIFIED="1432954394" TAGS="recipe,cooking,hot dog">40 Ways The World Makes Awesome Hot Dogs | Food Republic</A>
<DT><A HREF="http://www.thecomputermanual.com/fix-your-boot-with-bcdedit-bootsect-bcdboot-winre-and-winpe/" ADD_DATE="1431836110" LAST_VISIT="1431836110" LAST_MODIFIED="1431836110" TAGS="windows stuff,bcdboot,bcdsect,repair,boot">Fix Windows boot, Fix your Boot sequence with BcdEdit, BootSect, BCDboot, WINRE,...</A>
```

In the lines above, there are 3 instances of TAGS="*" which I've extracted here to make them easy to see:

```
TAGS="kundalini,yoga,fire breath,breathing,breath of fire"
TAGS="recipe,cooking,hot dog"
TAGS="windows stuff,bcdboot,bcdsect,repair,boot"
```

which, after the FIND/REPLACE, should look like:

```
TAGS="kundalini,yoga,fire-breath,breathing,breath-of-fire"
TAGS="recipe,cooking,hot-dog"
TAGS="windows-stuff,bcdboot,bcdsect,repair,boot"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following regex:

*Find what*: `(?:\G(?!^)|\bTAGS=")[^\s"]*\K\s+`
*Replace with*: `-`

**Details**:

- `(?:\G(?!^)|\bTAGS=")` - Finds either the end of the previous successful match (`\G(?!^)`) or
- `[^\s"]*` - 0+ chars other than a space and `"`
- `\K` - match reset operator discarding the text matched so far
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces

See the screenshot with settings below:

[image]

Comment: Holy cow. This was perfect. I'm still in awe of how flawlessly this worked. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2):

Use the following find/replace pattern in regex mode, and do a replace all to cover the entire document (or selection which you want).  Note that I make no effort to check for `TAGS="..."`, under the assumption that you don't have strings of the form `tag123` or `tag 123` anywhere else in your document.

**Find:**

```
tag\s+(\d*)
```

**Replace:**

```
tag-$1
```

**Input:**

```
tag1,tag2,tag 3,tag4,tag 5
```

**Output:**

```
tag1,tag2,tag-3,tag4,tag-5
```

Comment: @Sayse Actually, we don't need the comma at all, because the `(\d*)` pattern will stop at the end of the tag number anyway.

Comment: good answer! but this regex replaces only single space with *-*

Comment: Thank you, Tim! I should have used an actual sample from the text file rather than using Tag1,Tag2 like I did because the actual data in the file does not contain digits, which I think (from my limited understanding of regex) is what your solution is targeting.

I will update the original post with the actual data from the file.

Thank you again, it was my poor explanation of the problem.\